# Javascript average within multidimension array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, average

I have a 2D array, sorted by names of students and their various 100m sprint sessions. A snippet of the data array may look like this...

```
Names                 Time(s)

ANDREWMICHEALSMITH    13.95
JOHNJAMESPETERSON     13.70
JOHNJAMESPETERSON     13.80
JOHNJAMESPETERSON     12.50
PETERMICHEALHEWITT    12.80
PETERMICHEALHEWITT    12.60
VICENTJAMESSMITH      13.10
VICENTJAMESSMITH      13.50
VICENTJAMESSMITH      13.80
VICENTJAMESSMITH      13.00
```

I'm desperately needing to convert the table to show student name, their average time and the number of timed sessions, the desirable result as per below...

```
Names                 Avg Time(s) Sessions

ANDREWMICHEALSMITH    13.95       1
JOHNJAMESPETERSON     13.33       3
PETERMICHEALHEWITT    12.70       2
VICENTJAMESSMITH      13.35       4
```

I have drafted a JavaScript code so far unfortunately fails at the very first if statement.

> Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

The code also doesn't capture student with nth number of sessions, and no provision for number of sessions yet. Quite frankly my  Java knowledge is so limited for the task at hand. I'm in desperate need of some help to get to the end result.

I'm truely grateful for any guidance.

```
  StudentList.sort();

  for (var i=0; i<StudentList.length; i++){

    if(StudentList[i][0] == StudentList[i+1][0]){
      if(StudentList[i+1][0] == StudentList[i+2][0]){
        if(StudentList[i+2][0] == StudentList[i+3][0]){
          if(StudentList[i+3][0] == StudentList[i+4][0]){
            StudentList[i][1] = (StudentList[i][1]+StudentList[i+1][1]+StudentList[i+2][1]+StudentList[i+3][1]+StudentList[i+4][1])/5;
            StudentList.splice(i+1,3);
          }else{           
            StudentList[i][1] = (StudentList[i][1]+StudentList[i+1][1]+StudentList[i+2][1]+StudentList[i+3][1])/4;
          }
        }else{
          StudentList[i][1] = (StudentList[i][1]+StudentList[i+1][1]+StudentList[i+2][1])/3;
        }
      }else{
        StudentList[i][1] = (StudentList[i][1]+StudentList[i+1][1])/2;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where's your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object as hash table for names and us ean array as result set for counting and storing the data.

```js
var studentList = [['ANDREWMICHEALSMITH', 13.95], ['VICENTJAMESSMITH', 13.00], ['PETERMICHEALHEWITT', 12.80], ['PETERMICHEALHEWITT', 12.60], ['VICENTJAMESSMITH', 13.10], ['JOHNJAMESPETERSON', 13.70], ['JOHNJAMESPETERSON', 12.50], ['VICENTJAMESSMITH', 13.50], ['JOHNJAMESPETERSON', 13.80], ['VICENTJAMESSMITH', 13.80]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [],
    array;

studentList.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!hash[a[0]]) {
        hash[a[0]] = { name: a[0], sum: 0, count: 0, avg: 0 };
        result.push(hash[a[0]]);
    }
    hash[a[0]].sum += a[1];
    hash[a[0]].count++;
    hash[a[0]].avg = (hash[a[0]].sum / hash[a[0]].count).toFixed(2);
});

array = result.map(function (a) {
    return [a.name, a.avg, a.count];
});

console.log(array);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly, though I'm scratching my head what each line means for awhile yet. I would have never been able to come up with this myself.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but how do I go from "result", a table of objects(?), to an ordinary array like "studentList"? So I can write the data back to a spreadsheet. Thank you.

Comment: you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and render the values to an array.

Comment: This whole idea of object orientated arrays, properties and method are all pretty new to me I'm having a real tough time absorbing it all. However I'm starting to get how your code works. So powerful for what's seemingly minimal codes. Still struggling with understand how to, as per your suggestion, use array.map(), to get the object array back so I write to a spreadsheet. Ultimately I'd need to perform TargetSS.setValues(result);.

Comment: my bad, I have seen your updated code with method for map(), thank you so much